# escape double quotes inside double quotes and single quotes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, escaping

I want to apply this style:

```
 [ngClass]="{'login-form__text login-form__email' : '!displayErrors', 
                 'login-form__text login-form__email-confirm error': 'displayErrors && this.Form.get(\'email\').value !=\"" && !Form.valid && Form.errors?.mismatch'}"
```

unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("
```

And I'm sure it's because I have quotes inside my ngclass and I haven't properly escaped them. I tried to escape the double quote on the value check above. But it still shows the error.

How can I properly escape the string above?

Comment: isn't there an error in value !=\"" ... value !=\"\" or value != "" if you're using the template literal

Comment: look closely at the syntax highlighting in the question. `'login-form__text login-form__email-confirm error': 'displayErrors && this.Form.get('email').value ...` you're putting singles quotes inside of single quotes. after it is evaluated this will cause errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** pass an `expression` to `[ngClass]`, not **strings**:

Also, `displayErrors` is a `variable`, so you should use it as, of course, a variable.

```
[ngClass]="{'login-form__text login-form__email' : !displayErrors, 
            'login-form__text login-form__email-confirm error': displayErrors && 
            this.Form.get('email').value !== '' && Form.hasError('mismatch') }"
```

Or, if the email is `required`, you can simplify:

```
[ngClass]="{'login-form__text login-form__email' : !displayErrors, 
            'login-form__text login-form__email-confirm error': displayErrors && 
            !this.Form.get('email').hasError('required') && Form.hasError('mismatch') }"
```

**Tip:**

You don't need to check if the form is **not** valid and if has `mismatch` error, you can just check it has some *error* using `hasError()` method.

Comment: Is he even able to catch `Form` get object in view?

Comment: It still returns error, bro. There's something quite wrong in his expression. `this.Form.get('email').value !== ""` line is totally wrong.

Comment: @developer033, still doesn't work. Even if I use expressions vs. strings.

Comment: @Kinduser is right. There is something wrong with this line: this.Form.get('email').value !== "". Is there a better way to check for empty string?

Comment: @Euridice01 and @Kinduser, well it's correct. Anyway, the error must be in another part of your code. Did you attribute the `form` to variable (in your case `Form`)? Also, if the email is required, you can simply check using `hasError` as I said. `!this.form.get('email').hasError('required')`...

Comment: @developer033, can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @Euridice01, are you using `model driven` or `template driven` forms?

Comment: @developer033 model-driven.

Comment: So I suppose that you have this line in your `form` `<form [formGroup]="Form"...`, right? What's exactly not working now? Any errors?

Comment: @developer033 yup! :)

Comment: I still couldn't get the class to be applied but I'm accepting this answer since  the reason for the errors was because I was using a string and not an expression and use single quotes for value. That fixes the issue with the original question.